How to add a custom row to order table in WooCommerce admin order page
I am trying to add a custom row to order table in WooCommerce order page. But the code I have tried is not working.

I tried using this woocommerce_admin_order_item_values() hook but it's not working.
This is my code:
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'replace_quantity_td_content', 99999, 3);

function replace_quantity_td_content($product, $item, $item_id) {
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
    $meta_data_array = $item->get_meta_data(); 
    
    foreach ($meta_data_array as $meta) {
        $meta_value_array = $meta->value;
        if (isset($meta_value_array['tabNumber'])) {
            $tab_number = $meta_value_array['tabNumber'];   
            if ($tab_number === 'square-meter-li') {
                $quantity_display = $quantity . ' m2'; 
            }
            echo  $quantity_display ; 
        }
    }
}


It seems like you’re trying to add a custom column to the WooCommerce order page/ order edit page.
What you will need is to add the column name and the value by using the following hooks:

my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers function to add the column
header
my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values function to add the column
value
Add javascript to reorder the columns (alternatively you need to restructure the html-order-items.php file, which is part of the WooCommerce admin interface and is used to display the order items in the order edit screen)

Things to keep in mind, before adding this code:

The code assumes that the order edit page uses the post type shop_order. If the store has customized the post type for orders, the code may not work as expected.

The code also assumes that the order table includes a column with the class quantity. If the store has customized the order table and this column is not present, the code may not work as expected.

The code is designed to add a new column to the order table. If the store has already added a column with the class item_m2, there could be conflicts.

The JavaScript code uses jQuery, so it requires that jQuery is loaded on the order edit page.

The code only adds the column to order edit page. It means that this custom column will not display in the checkout, cart, order emails, or any other places.

The value m2 is static, hardcoded. Meaning that the value is not stored anywhere, but merely for display purpose on order edit page.

This code will display the column and value for all orders.


To add the custom column, and a static value you can use the following:
// Add custom column header in order table
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'add_custom_order_item_header');
function add_custom_order_item_header() {
    echo '<th class="item_m2" style="display:none;">In m2</th>'; // Name of the header
}

// Add custom static value to line items, in custom column, in order table
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'add_custom_order_item_value', 10, 3);
function add_custom_order_item_value($product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    // Check if $item is a valid object and if it's a line item
    if (is_object($item) && $item->get_type() == 'line_item') {
        echo '<td class="item_m2" style="display:none;">';
        // Your custom static value here
        echo 'm2';
        echo '</td>';
        }

}

These hooks don’t provide a way to control the position of the new column. If you want to add a new column after a specific column (like the quantity column), you would need to modify the HTML structure of the table directly.
You can also achieve this by using JavaScript/jQuery to manipulate the DOM structure and insert your custom column after the quantity column.
To use Javascript, you can use the following:
// Add custom script to reorder custom column in order table
add_action('admin_footer', 'reorder_custom_column');
function reorder_custom_column() {
    if ('shop_order' === get_post_type()) : // Check if it's the order edit page
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                // Check if the m2 column and quantity column exist
                if ($('th.item_m2').length && $('th.quantity').length) {
                    // Move the m2 column after the quantity column
                    var m2Header = $('th.item_m2');
                    m2Header.insertAfter($('th.quantity'));

                    var m2Cells = $('td.item_m2');
                    m2Cells.each(function() {
                        $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity'));
                    });

                    // Show the m2 column
                    m2Header.show();
                    m2Cells.show();
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}

The codes should be placed in the bottom of your functions.php file of your child theme.
Summary:

I used the hook my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers function to add the header to the column
header
I used the hook my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values function to add the the static value to the column
value
I added inline-css display:none; to hide the new column and row. The reason for this is that the placement of the new column (with class=item_m2) is being controlled by JavaScript. The column is initially hidden to prevent it from appearing in the wrong place before the JavaScript has a chance to run.
Once the page has loaded, the JavaScript code checks if the item_m2 class column and the quantity column exist. If they do, it moves the item_m2 column to the desired location (after the quantity column) and then shows the item_m2 column by calling the show() method, which changes the CSS display property to block or inline, depending on what it was originally.
The code is specifically designed to only run on the order edit page. This is controlled by the condition if ('shop_order' === get_post_type()) in the reorder_custom_column function. The get_post_type() function returns the type of the current post being processed in the WordPress Loop. The condition checks if the current post type is shop_order, which is the post type for the order edit page in WooCommerce. If the current post type is not shop_order, the condition will be false and the JavaScript code inside the reorder_custom_column function will not be executed.


Thank you Richard. This is exactly what I was looking for, simple and clear code. Tested and works!
